# How do you hide the taskbar in WPF in a Windows 10 Desktop application?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

How do you hide the taskbar in WPF in a Windows 10 Desktop application?

I've looked around and this is the closest I've gotten, but I can't get the taskbar to hide.

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
```

I'm working with WPF, NET Core and this is a Windows 10 desktop application. I've surf the web and have seen this suggested but still does not work.

```
this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
this.Top = 0;
this.Left = 0;
this.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
this.Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
this.MaxWidth = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
```

I want a true Full Screen, no title bar and no taskbar, the same way a slideshow or a powerpoint slidehow hides both.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the first code block should suffice. You can try adding  `AllowsTransparency = True`.

Comment: Disabling and/or hiding Windows taskbar: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e231f5be-5233-4eee-b142-7aef50f37287/disabling-andor-hiding-windows-taskbar?forum=csharpgeneral](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e231f5be-5233-4eee-b142-7aef50f37287/disabling-andor-hiding-windows-taskbar?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Sorry I wanted the user to be able to click a fullscreen button and give the desired action in runtime. AllowsTransparency is giving me problems changing the value in runtime, but is what I am trying to do if you start the program with WindowsStyle None and AllowsTransparency True.....How can I have a user go back and forth from fullscreen with a command or button?

Comment: @Jackdaw Taskbar class removes taskbar but does not expand window to take the space of the taskbar. Also someone in that post mention this wasn't a good way to achieve hiding the taskbar....any ideas?

Comment: If you already have the full screen, there are many options. The logic will be to set the state of the window to `Normal`. This will do a kind of restore. To achieve this, it depends how you want your application to work. You can listen to keyboard inputs or mouse clicks.

Answer (score 1):

It will be enough for you to just apply these three codes.

```
this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Alternatively, you can implement it in xaml code like this.

```
ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got what I was trying to achieve by doing this

```
this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Putting the WindowState to Normal and then putting to Maximized hides the taskbar.

I believe **bolkay** was pointing that out in his comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with this code, it is not displayed in the taskbar, and it blocks the taskbar in full screen.

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
this.ResizeMode= ResizeMode.NoResize;
```

I guess you're using a custom theme library, and I've had similar problems.You can try this:

```
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}"/>
</Window.Style>
```